# How to use recursive function to produce a 1-D array in PHP that contains a hierarchical comment reply system?

Tags: php, arrays, function, recursion

I have 2 tables. Table 'comments' contains all the comments with cid ,comment as fields. and another table 'reply' which consists of cid and rpid which stores which comment is the reply of which comment.

```
function array_gen($c, $array, $total, $conn, $f) {
  $array[] = $c;
  $sql = "SELECT rpid FROM reply WHERE cmid = '$c';";
  $st = $conn->query($sql);
  $st->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $rpid = $st->fetchAll();
  $count = $st -> rowCount();
  if ($count > 0) {
    foreach ($rpid as $r) {
      $array = array_gen($r['rpid'], $array, $total, $conn, $f);
    }
  }
  else {
    echo $c;
    return $array;
  }
  while ($f <= $total) {
    if (! in_array($f, $array)) {
      $array = array_gen($f, $array, $total, $conn, $f);
    }
    $f++;
  }
  return $array; 
}
```

I tried out a function with parameters total number of comments ($total), first comment ($c), empty array ($array), a flag variable $f initialised to value of $c and a PDO connection variable $conn.
It works perfectly upto 2 level of comment-reply. But when it comes to 3rd level i.e, a reply is given to another reply, it starts misbehaving. Function return is not working properly inside foreach loop.

Comment: Difficult to test (unless you provide test data) but when you use `$array = array_gen($r..` this overwrites any current data, try using `$array[] = array_gen($r...` to keep all of the results.

Comment: @NigelRen I have to produce an array [1,3,5,2,4,6,7,9,8] . 1,2,3 & 8 are the comments in first level. 3&5 are replies to 1. 6&9 are replies to 4. 7 is the reply to 6. What i get as output when i run on this test case is [1,3,5,2,4,6,7,8,9,9]